# Is it valid to crosspost the same question by offering bounties?

Tags: support, questions, bounties

I've placed bounty on [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/191832/25879). For some reason this question has not received enough attention. Can I ask the same on Stack Overflow by offering bounty on it?

I know it's not valid to ask the same question on Stack Overflow and Drupal Answers.But is it OK to ask the same question on different communities by offering bounties on each?

Comment: Just delete it over here first and yeah, no problem at all. Bounties don't affect the no-cross-site-duplicate rule if that's what you mean?

Comment: yes @Clive that's what I mean. Got it thanks :)

Comment: eh, no one would've noticed... now they're watching you like a hawk =(

Comment: @NoSssweat :D :D. hmm.. now I'm worrying about my task deadline, Until the bounty is still active, the question cannot be closed nor deleted. The bounty question not getting enough attention. :(

Comment: @KrishnaMohan perhaps you need to up the bounty :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting the same question on two Stack Exchange sites without tailoring it for the site is something Stack Exchange suggest not to do.

If you are going to ask the same exact question, I would delete the question on *Drupal Answers*, but you can do that only after the bounty expired. Until the bounty is still active, the question cannot be closed nor deleted.